# Isomorphic to the Klein 4 group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I need to prove the group of the units of $\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3$ is isomorphic to the Klein-4 group. But I'm really struggling to prove this. Any hints to start me off in the right direction??

Comment: List the units of $\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3$.  Whot you have?

Comment: First step: have you determined which elements are units, and this how many units there are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's really only one thing you can do: list the units of $\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3$, see if there are four of them, and then figure out whether or not they form a cyclic group.

Answer (score 3):

Start with figuring out the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}_3$.  Then, how does the unit group of $\mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_3$ differ?